# Embulkでorg.embulk.config.ConfigExceptionの原因が分からない。

Tags: java

RDS for PostgreSQLから、自宅サーバのPostgreSQLへデータの転送をしようと考えています。
embulk previewは問題無く通るのですが、runしてみると例外がでてエラーとなってしまいます。
原因が分かりますでしょうか？

Embulk v0.8.9
PostgreSQL 9.5.2
CentOS 7

in側テーブル

```
CREATE TABLE public.tt_test_fav
(
  status_id bigint NOT NULL,
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  tp smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  user_id bigint,
  user_rank smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT tt_test_fav_pkey PRIMARY KEY (status_id, id, tp)
);
```

out側テーブル

```
CREATE TABLE public.tt_test_fav
(
  status_id bigint NOT NULL,
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  tp smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  user_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT tt_test_fav_pkey PRIMARY KEY (status_id, id, tp)
);
```

最後のカラム user_rank を除いて転送したい

yaml

```
in:
  type: postgresql
  host: hoge.rds.amazonaws.com
  port: 5432
  user: hoge
  password: hoge
  database: hoge
  table: tt_test_fav
  select: status_id, id, tp, user_id
  column_options:
    status_id: {value_type: long}
    id: {value_type: long}
    tp: {value_type: long}
    user_id: {value_type: long}

out:
  type: postgresql
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  user: hoge
  password: hoge
  database: hoge
  table: tt_test_fav
  mode: merge
  merge_keys: status_id, id, tp
  column_options:
    status_id: {value_type: long}
    id: {value_type: long}
    tp: {value_type: long}
    user_id: {value_type: long}
```

コンソールに出力されるエラー

```
2016-07-09 21:19:35.222 +0900: Embulk v0.8.9
2016-07-09 21:19:36.750 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Loaded plugin embulk-input-postgresql (0.7.2)
2016-07-09 21:19:36.963 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Loaded plugin embulk-output-postgresql (0.6.1)
2016-07-09 21:19:38.043 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): SQL: SET search_path TO "public"
2016-07-09 21:19:38.447 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): SQL: SELECT status_id, id, tp, user_id FROM "tt_test_fav"
2016-07-09 21:19:38.861 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Using local thread executor with max_threads=40 / output tasks 20 = input tasks 1 * 20
org.embulk.exec.PartialExecutionException: org.embulk.config.ConfigException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$LoaderState.buildPartialExecuteException(org/embulk/exec/BulkLoader.java:363)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doRun(org/embulk/exec/BulkLoader.java:572)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.access$000(org/embulk/exec/BulkLoader.java:33)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(org/embulk/exec/BulkLoader.java:374)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(org/embulk/exec/BulkLoader.java:370)
    at org.embulk.spi.Exec.doWith(org/embulk/spi/Exec.java:25)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.run(org/embulk/exec/BulkLoader.java:370)
    at org.embulk.EmbulkEmbed.run(org/embulk/EmbulkEmbed.java:180)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:498)
    at RUBY.run(/home/osa/.embulk/bin/embulk!/embulk/runner.rb:84)
    at RUBY.run(/home/osa/.embulk/bin/embulk!/embulk/command/embulk_run.rb:306)
    at RUBY.<top>(/home/osa/.embulk/bin/embulk!/embulk/command/embulk_main.rb:2)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:937)
    at RUBY.(root)(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1)
    at home.osa.$_dot_embulk.bin.embulk.embulk.command.embulk_bundle.<top>(file:/home/osa/.embulk/bin/embulk!/embulk/command/embulk_bundle.rb:51)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.embulk.cli.Main.main(org/embulk/cli/Main.java:23)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doCleanup(BulkLoader.java:479)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$3.run(BulkLoader.java:410)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$3.run(BulkLoader.java:406)
        at org.embulk.spi.Exec.doWith(Exec.java:25)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.cleanup(BulkLoader.java:406)
        at org.embulk.EmbulkEmbed.run(EmbulkEmbed.java:184)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:452)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:313)
        at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:45)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:313)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:163)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:316)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:77)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:140)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:126)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:273)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:79)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:83)
        at org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:414)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:348)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:77)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:86)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:210)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:196)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:197)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:313)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:163)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:316)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:77)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(Interpreter.java:112)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:99)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:35)
        at org.jruby.ir.IRTranslator.execute(IRTranslator.java:42)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:833)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:2905)
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$ResourceLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:235)
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$FoundLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:34)
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.tryLoadingLibraryOrScript(LoadService.java:900)
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.smartLoadInternal(LoadService.java:541)
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.requireCommon(LoadService.java:426)
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.require(LoadService.java:392)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.requireCommon(RubyKernel.java:944)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require19(RubyKernel.java:937)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require19.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require19.gen)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:380)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:61)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:313)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:163)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:316)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:77)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:86)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:210)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:196)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:197)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:313)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:163)
        at home.osa.$_dot_embulk.bin.embulk.embulk.command.embulk_bundle.invokeOther66:require(file:/home/osa/.embulk/bin/embulk!/embulk/command/embulk_bundle.rb)
        at home.osa.$_dot_embulk.bin.embulk.embulk.command.embulk_bundle.RUBY$script(file:/home/osa/.embulk/bin/embulk!/embulk/command/embulk_bundle.rb:51)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
        at org.jruby.ir.Compiler$1.load(Compiler.java:111)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:817)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:809)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:747)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:569)
        at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:415)
        at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:310)
        at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:239)
        at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:201)
        at org.embulk.cli.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: org.embulk.config.ConfigException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
    at org.embulk.config.ModelManager.readObjectWithConfigSerDe(ModelManager.java:75)
    at org.embulk.config.DataSourceImpl.loadConfig(DataSourceImpl.java:220)
    at org.embulk.output.jdbc.AbstractJdbcOutputPlugin.transaction(AbstractJdbcOutputPlugin.java:321)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$4$1$1.transaction(BulkLoader.java:529)
    at org.embulk.exec.LocalExecutorPlugin.transaction(LocalExecutorPlugin.java:54)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$4$1.run(BulkLoader.java:524)
    at org.embulk.spi.util.Filters$RecursiveControl.transaction(Filters.java:96)
    at org.embulk.spi.util.Filters.transaction(Filters.java:49)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$4.run(BulkLoader.java:518)
    at org.embulk.input.jdbc.AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.transaction(AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.java:163)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doRun(BulkLoader.java:513)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.access$000(BulkLoader.java:33)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:374)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:370)
    at org.embulk.spi.Exec.doWith(Exec.java:25)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.run(BulkLoader.java:370)
    at org.embulk.EmbulkEmbed.run(EmbulkEmbed.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:452)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:313)
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:45)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:313)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:163)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:316)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:77)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:140)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:126)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:273)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:79)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:83)
    at org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:414)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:348)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:77)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:86)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:210)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:196)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:197)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:313)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:163)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:316)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:77)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(Interpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:99)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:35)
    at org.jruby.ir.IRTranslator.execute(IRTranslator.java:42)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:833)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:2905)
    at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$ResourceLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:235)
    at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$FoundLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:34)
    at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.tryLoadingLibraryOrScript(LoadService.java:900)
    at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.smartLoadInternal(LoadService.java:541)
    at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.requireCommon(LoadService.java:426)
    at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.require(LoadService.java:392)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.requireCommon(RubyKernel.java:944)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require19(RubyKernel.java:937)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require19.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require19.gen)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:380)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:61)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:313)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:163)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:316)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:77)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:86)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:210)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:196)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:197)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:313)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:163)
    at home.osa.$_dot_embulk.bin.embulk.embulk.command.embulk_bundle.invokeOther66:require(file:/home/osa/.embulk/bin/embulk!/embulk/command/embulk_bundle.rb)
    at home.osa.$_dot_embulk.bin.embulk.embulk.command.embulk_bundle.RUBY$script(file:/home/osa/.embulk/bin/embulk!/embulk/command/embulk_bundle.rb:51)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.jruby.ir.Compiler$1.load(Compiler.java:111)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:817)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:809)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:747)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:569)
    at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:415)
    at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:310)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:239)
    at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:201)
    at org.embulk.cli.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:835)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:831)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringCollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(StringCollectionDeserializer.java:240)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringCollectionDeserializer.deserialize(StringCollectionDeserializer.java:171)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringCollectionDeserializer.deserialize(StringCollectionDeserializer.java:161)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringCollectionDeserializer.deserialize(StringCollectionDeserializer.java:19)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.deser.GuavaOptionalDeserializer.deserialize(GuavaOptionalDeserializer.java:98)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.deser.GuavaOptionalDeserializer.deserialize(GuavaOptionalDeserializer.java:18)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3534)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1894)
    at org.embulk.config.TaskSerDe$TaskDeserializer.deserialize(TaskSerDe.java:161)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3534)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1870)
    at org.embulk.config.ModelManager.readObjectWithConfigSerDe(ModelManager.java:72)
    ... 83 more

Error: org.embulk.config.ConfigException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/embulk/embulk-output-jdbc/tree/master/embulk-output-postgresql

> merge_keys: key column names for merging records in merge mode (string array, required in merge mode)

となっているのでmerge_keyは配列で書きます。

```
merge_keys:
  - status_id
  - id
  - tp
```

あるいは`merge_keys: [ status_id, id, tp]`です。

こちらで試した設定の例です。

```
in:
  type: postgresql
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 5432
  user: user
  password: pass
  database: embulk_test
  table: tt_test_fav
  select: status_id, id, tp, user_id

out:
  type: postgresql
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 5432
  user: user
  password: pass
  database: embulk_test
  table: tt_test_fav_out
  mode: merge
  merge_keys:
    - status_id
    - id
    - tp
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。上手く行きました。yamlの書き方が間違っていたんですね。guess通した後だったので、書式は問題ないものだと勘違いしていました。